# Will you grab - we'you grab

Tags: pronunciation, contractions, fast-speech-rules

I was watching a film with subtitles, and the phrase:
"Will you grab her blanket?" sounded like "We'you graber blanket". I'm Ok with "graber", but can we drop "l"-sound in "will you"?

Comment: You have asked a yes-no question, but either answer would be so misleading as to be wrong.

Comment: You can drop any sound you wish.  But, will people still understand you is the question.  Unless you're in an area where people routinely drop that sound, it's unlikely people will readily understand you.

Comment: _Will you_ is virtually always contracted to /'wiyu/. In fact, _will_ by itself is almost always contracted, if possible with a pronoun (_I'll, you'll, he'll, it'll, they'll, we'll_, and also _will you_ as noted, and /'wɪli, 'wɪlət, 'wɪlay, 'wɪðe/ for _will he, will it, will I, will they_).

Comment: @tchrist I don’t see how “yes” could possibly be misleading. Yes, we can definitely drop the /l/ in _will you_; we can also, in some contexts more likely than in others, retain it, but I can think of pretty much no context where you _couldn’t_ drop it. Even when emphasising _will_, the /l/ drops quite readily for me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet A one-bit answer gives insufficient nuance to be useful to the asker.

Comment: @tchrist A one-bit answer would not be an adequate ELU answer to begin with, no matter how simple the yes/no question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> *Will you* is virtually always contracted to /'wiyu/. In fact, *will* by itself is almost always contracted, if possible with a pronoun (*I'll, you'll, he'll, it'll, they'll, we'll*, and also *will you* as noted, and /'wɪli, 'wɪlət, 'wɪlay, 'wɪðe/ for *will he, will it, will I, will they*).